# Como obter dados dinâmicos retornados pelo cURL?

Tags: php, api, rest, libcurl

Boa noite, preciso retornar dados de um site específico para a minha aplicação, para isso escolhi usar o método cURL() PHP, nele envio um post e retorno a informação que desejo, o problema é que nesse retorno vem a página completa do formulário que acessei, não achei nenhuma maneira de pegar apenas os dados das inputs desse formulário. Preciso capturar a informação retornada do formulário e passar para json.

Aqui está o método que realiza essa busca:

```
public function busca(Request $request){

    $data = $request->all();

      $cURL = curl_init('http://www.site.com.br/resultado.php');

      curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
      curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

      $dados = array(
        'num_cnpj' => $data['cnpj'],
        'botao' => 'Consultar'

      );
      curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POST, true);
      curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dados);
      curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.site.com.br/index.php');

      $resultado = curl_exec($cURL);

      curl_close($cURL);

      return $resultado;
}
```

Comment: As informações são retornadas dentro de Inputs? Se possível adicione o HTML retornado (pelo menos no trecho que deseja obter os dados).

Comment: Sim, funciona como se ele tirasse uma copia da página completa onde os dados são retornados do site original, e os dados que desejo capturar estão dentro das inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você vai precisar entender sobre expressão regular para recortar partes do que você deseja extrair do HTML ou se não você pode estudar essa lib nativa do PHP http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php ele pode simular DOM do javascript para acessar o html node.

Se os dados que você quer pegar forem pouca coisa eu recomendo expressão regular.

Mas se for muita coisa eu recomendo usar o DOM.

Exemplo usando o DOM:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($html);
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('link');

foreach ($links as $link) {
  print_r($link->getAttributes());
}
```

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta, funcionou.